# Read configuration parameter in postgresql using JDBC

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, configuration-files, postgresql-9.2

I have set a configuration parameter in postgresql 9.2.4 in the following way in Datastudio

```
SET foo.test = 'foo.test'
```

I can access that value in Datastudio using

```
SELECT current_setting('foo.test')
```

However I am not able to access that value using JDBC. 
I get the following error :

> *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "foo.test"*

Comment: `SET` sets setting for session - do you share same session?..

Comment: Yes..They have different sessions

Comment: How can i set a configuration parameter permanently?

Comment: depends on which level you want it. `alter user set`, `alter database set` and o on

Answer (score 0):

you probably run Datastudio and jdbs in different sessions, and `SET` sets setting for session.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html

> SET only affects the value used by the current session.

or `SET LOCAL` that  affects current transaction only